# why am i having this python import error when ive already installed the module?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

Right so I having been trying to set up my raspberry pi 4 for a while now because I want to run a bot kind of system on it and I know all my code works and stuff but when I try and run the program on my pi it says it doesn't have modules I need, specifically for its TTS.

If anyone can get back  to me that would be great.

I have already tried a pip install (pip install gtts and pip install pyttsx3 (this is the alternative module if gtts doesn't work)).

Comment: If you could provide the code you are using, including any `import` statements, that would help anyone who wants to answer this question.

Comment: I always have these kinds of issues with python. Often times its related to the virtual environment. try "sudo -H pip3 install <package>